# Prevent the child class of an abstract class from creating new methods

Tags: python, abstract-class, abstract-methods

Is it possible to force a child class to have all the methods of the abstract class?

I have the following example:

```
class MovementsService(ABC):

  @abstractmethod
  def run():
    pass
```

and the child class:

```
class People(MovementsService):

  def run():
    print("im running")

  def move():
    print("im moving")
```

but I wouldn't want the child class "People" to have the possibility to implement functions that it doesn't have in the abstract class. Is this possible?

I don't know if this is a good practice either, so I am open to hear opposing opinions.

but in my case it would make sense to block the ability to create new functions because I am using the abstract class as an "interface" to one of my project's dependencies...

Comment: you simply can't do that in python, python doesn't really allow any constraint on what the users can do .... like ever, there's always going to be a way around what you'll try to do.

Comment: You could do something with `__init_subclass__` to raise an `AttributeError` if `cls` has any unexpected attributes, but I don't really see how that would help you with your use case. (Interfaces typically don't *ban* an implementing class from defining certain methods; they just *require* certain methods be defined.)

Comment: pt.1 - In my case I am using the abstract class to perform a dependency inversion, I would like any other dependency that was implemented from this abstract class to depend 100% on its methods.

Comment: pt.2 - Imagine I create a method "InsertInTheBankDatabase" in a child class of the abstract class, but this method is not in my abstract class defined as @abstractmethod, when I need to change the dependency of my project  I will have to look in the class where the function "InsertInTheBankDatabase" was declared. This is wrong in my view, because I could always be looking at the abstract class as the basis for all the dependencies that inherit it...

Comment: pt.3 - so I would know that all the child classes only contain the X functions of the parent class. I could look at the abstract class and check "well in the abstract class I have the function 'start' so I will have to implement in the class of the new dependency the start method too", but me having the permission to create new methods in the dependency class is dangerous because it can let other developers code some function that is invoked and that changes the behavior of a part of the system and then I would be dependent on the dependency class not the abstract class...

Comment: pt.4 - That way I would make sure that my interface class defined that in all dependencies I would only have X functions...

but I might be thinking wrong about this implementation, I'm just sharing my doubts, I know this implementation could be wrong too, if someone can give me some hints, that would be great :)

Comment: What if someone found it convenient to write a single object that is a MomentsService and something else also that conforms to a different interface?

Comment: This would break the idea of the abstract class, because the abstract class in question should contain only the methods that the child class should contain, so we can control exactly which methods the dependency class contains.
if at some point I want to change some dependency, I just look at the abstract class and implement the same methods it contains in the new dependency class, and inherit the abstract class into it...

Comment: It doesn't look like you have a firm grasp on the concepts. An abstract class doesn't limit what concrete classes may not contain. If the concrete class implements all of the methods and contracts required by the abstract class, it doesn't matter if it has other content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `__init_subclass__` to detect unexpected attributes in a subclass (at least, those appearing in the class's `__dict__` attribute). I'm not really sure why this would be necessary, though.

```
class MovementsService(ABC):

  @abstractmethod
  def run():
    pass

  def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
      super().__init__(**kwargs)
      for attr in cls.__dict__:
          if attr != "run":
              raise AttributeError(f"Attribute '{attr}' not allowed")
```

You can refine the check to only disallow callable attributes, only attributes of type `function` (allowing class methods and static methods), etc.

Comment: pt.1 - In my case I am using the abstract class to perform a dependency inversion, I would like any other dependency that was implemented from this abstract class to depend 100% on its methods.

Comment: pt.2 - Imagine I create a method "InsertInTheBankDatabase" in a child class of the abstract class, but this method is not in my abstract class defined as @abstractmethod, when I need to change the dependency of my project I will have to look in the class where the function "InsertInTheBankDatabase" was declared. This is wrong in my view, because I could always be looking at the abstract class as the basis for all the dependencies that inherit it...

Comment: pt.3 - so I would know that all the child classes only contain the X functions of the parent class. I could look at the abstract class and check "well in the abstract class I have the function 'start' so I will have to implement in the class of the new dependency the start method too", but me having the permission to create new methods in the dependency class is dangerous because it can let other developers code some function that is invoked and that changes the behavior of a part of the system and then I would be dependent on the dependency class not the abstract class...

Comment: pt.4 - That way I would make sure that my interface class defined that in all dependencies I would only have X functions... but I might be thinking wrong about this implementation, I'm just sharing my doubts, I know this implementation could be wrong too, if someone can give me some hints, that would be great :)